# With R changing row names of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a Dataframe [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txlnc.png)

My column names are **F02283_L1_S49_L006, F02284_L1_S50_L006** etc. which is totally fine.

But my row names are **1,2,3,4** etc. and i dont want that. Instead of that i want **ENSG00000182199, ENSG00000157870** etc.

Im new in R and i have to process this dataframe. I will my dataframe as a matrix, so they muss contain just numeric values. How can i do that with R?

Comment: Looks like your row names are in a column named `Genes`, so something like `row.names(my_data) <- my_data$Genes` will set the row names. Then you can delete the gene column and convert to matrix.

Comment: or if you want a matrix, you can `df_m<-as.matrix(df[,-1]); rownames(df_m)<-df$Genes`

Comment: You have to give a demonstrative example  in code of your problem then give a demonstration of the type of result you want then you will get help.